# LEN Extra Spaces

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have an issue which I just cant figure out. I have a spreadsheet with numbers formatted as text which I want to import into an SQL database. In the database the numbers are preceded with a leading space depending on the length 
e.g. "   1"), "  10", " 100"

So in my code I check the length then add appropriate spaces but it seems to be adding more for some unknown reason but then if I print the display it is the correct amount ?

```
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
rs.Open strquery, cn

rs.MoveFirst 
if rs.BOF = true and rs.EOF = true then
response.Write "Error:: Products spreadsheet is empty!"
else
while not rs.EOF
response.Write rs.Fields(0) & " " & rs.Fields(1) & "<BR><BR>"
orderno= rs.Fields(0)
lineno = rs.Fields(1)
confirmed= rs.Fields(2)
tracking= rs.Fields(3)
carrier= rs.Fields(4)

if orderno = ""  or isnull(orderno) then
else
orderno = replace(orderno,"'","")
lineno = replace(lineno,"'","")
lineno = trim(lineno)

RESPONSE.WRITE("Start lengh:"&(LEN(lineno)))

if len(lineno=1) then
lineno = "   "&lineno&""
end if

if len(lineno=2) then
lineno = "  "&lineno&""
end if

if len(lineno=3) then
lineno = " "&lineno&""
end if


RESPONSE.WRITE("Mid lengh:"&(LEN(lineno)))
response.write("hello1"&lineno&"hello2")
```

Based on the code above the print out at start length is 1 and the print out at mid length is 7 - but I am only specifying to add 3 spaces. The value should be 4 characters with leading spaces infront. Any help much appreciated, really don't understand what is going on !

Answer (score 3):

You have just misplaced the closing bracket.

`if len(lineno=1) then`

should be:

`if len(lineno)=1 then`

Likewise for the other checks.

And for printing multiple spaces in HTML, use [`&nbsp;`](http://dimaroan.home.xs4all.nl/htl/faq1.html) for each space you need.